# Teradata/SQL : How to compare dates in consecutive rows using teradata SQL and write case statement on the result

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to compare a date (end dt) in 1st row with the date (strt dt) in secord row, if it matches I need to pick up strt dt of 2nd row.
if it dosent match I need to pick up strt dt of 1st row. There can be multiple rows for one subscription and channel package.
I am finding difficulty in writting a query in teradata to get the desired output.

Below are the cases and expected results.

Case 1

```
Subscription    Channel package Start dt    End dt
11111112    Sports  7/3/2015    11/28/2015
11111112    Sports  4/1/2016    11/23/2016
11111112    Sports  11/23/2016  12/17/2017
```

Require Output

```
Subscription    Channel package Start dt    End dt
11111112    Sports  4/1/2016    12/17/2017
```

Case 2

```
Subscription    Channel package Start dt    End dt
11111112    Sports  7/3/2015    11/28/2015
11111112    Sports  11/28/2015  4/1/2016
11111112    Sports  4/1/2016    11/23/2016
11111112    Sports  11/23/2016  12/17/2017
```

Require Output

```
Subscription    Channel package Start dt    End dt
11111112    Sports  7/3/2015    12/17/2017
```

I tried it using

```
MIN(Start dt) OVER (PARTITION BY Subscription   , Channel package   
                    ORDER BY Start dt ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING  AND 1 FOLLOWING
                   ) AS NXT Start dt
```

But couldn't go further as i m facing some issues while using qualify.

Comment: Window functions do not reduce the number of rows.  Your question is unclear.  What happens to the rows where the condition is not met?  What if multiple rows in sequence meet the conditions?  What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes so if multiple rows meets the condition where 2nd row strt dt is matching with 1st row end dt that does mean that the channel package for the subscription did not end and its a false closing then i want the minimum of start date. But in case there is gap in last ending and next starting then its a correct closure and I want the date on which it started next. There should be one row for subscription and channel package combination in results.

Comment: This question is really unclear.  I would suggest that you delete this question (it has no answers).  Ask another question.  Provide a single table with three or so different examples.  Show the results that you want.  Explain the logic for combining rows together.  The concept of "compare to next row" is not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: It appears that Aniket is looking to collapse chains that are continuous sequences based on the Subscription and Channel Package. I think this can be done with windowed aggregates and derived tables, I just haven’t had time to mock up data in an instance of Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may come as a late solution or may not be the quickest one.
I would start like this:

```
(
     SELECT
             TBL.SUBSCRIPTION
         ,   TBL.CHANNEL
         ,   TBL.SUBSCRIPTION || TBL.CHANNEL AS SUB_CHANNEL
         ,   CASE WHEN TBL.END_DT = TBL.START_DT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SAME_DAY_FLAG
         ,   Dense_Rank() Over (ORDER BY SUB_CHANNEL ) AS GRP_RANK
         ,   TBL.START_DT
         ,   TBL.END_DT
         ,   PERIOD(TBL.START_DT, CASE WHEN TBL.END_DT > DATE THEN DATE ELSE TBL.END_DT + 1 END) AS COVERD_DTES
         
     FROM    <YOUR_TABLE> AS TBL
) WITH DATA
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Create index as needed. The reason for creating `SUB_CHANNEL` is because for some silly reason I cannot put my finger on, I am unable to pull more than one column for some functions below.

```
/* Create a table that will contain the Merged rows with proper start and end dates combining adjacent periods*/

CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_TBL_MERGED_ROWS AS
(
    WITH  CTE (GRP_RANK, COVERD_DTES) AS
    (
        SELECT 
                GRP_RANK, COVERD_DTES
        FROM VT_PRE_CTE 
        
    )
    SELECT * FROM TABLE
    (    
        TD_SYSFNLIB.Td_Normalize_Overlap_Meet(NEW VARIANT_TYPE( CTE.GRP_RANK),  CTE.COVERD_DTES)
        RETURNS (GRP_RANK INT, COVERD_DTES PERIOD(DATE))
        HASH BY  GRP_RANK
        LOCAL ORDER BY GRP_RANK, COVERD_DTES
     )  AS TBL_ROWS
    
)   WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX (GRP_RANK);
```

The function `TD_SYSFNLIB.Td_Normalize_Overlap_Meet` normalizes the overlapping end and start dates and gives you a single row of the lowest and the last start and end date respectively. Since I could not fathom a way to pass multiple columns, I created the `GRP_RANK` that I can then tie back.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_PRE_OUTPUT AS 
(SELECT 
                A.SUBSCRIPTION
            ,   A.CHANNEL
            ,   A.GRP_RANK
            ,   B.COVERD_DTES
            ,   Min(A.EFF_DT) AS EFF_DT
            ,   Max(A.EXP_DT) AS EXP_DT
            ,   End(B.COVERD_DTES)- Begin(B.COVERD_DTES) AS TOTAL_DAYS
        FROM    VT_PRE_CTE AS A
        JOIN    VT_TBL_MERGED_ROWS AS B
        ON      A.GRP_RANK = B.GRP_RANK 
        AND     A.COVERD_DTES OVERLAPS B.COVERD_DTES
        GROUP BY 1,2,3) 
        WITH DATA 
        PRIMARY INDEX(MTN,  EXP_DT)
        ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

This `A.COVERD_DTES OVERLAPS B.COVERD_DTES` actually will give you multiple rows if there is a break between the `SUBSCRIPTION/CHANNEL` combination.
You can decide what to do with the multiple fragments, either using `QUALIFY Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSCRIPTION, CHANNEL ORDER BY MIN_DT ASC) = 1`  to get the first occurrence or `ORDER BY MIN_DT DESC)`  to get the latest occurrence.